# How to space out icons in navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

I have a Google icon bar in my header. I'd like to space out the icons so that they have space between them. However, when I shrink my browser window the "share icon" disappears. Can anyone help as to how I can keep it in the viewport?

```css
  * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px
}

#share {
  margin-left: 1200px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Figtree', sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background: #212529;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 120px auto;
  padding: 0px 80px;
  background: white;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined" rel="stylesheet">


<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Figtree:wght@500&family=Inter:wght@100;300;400;500&family=Montserrat&family=Plus+Jakarta+Sans:wght@400;500&family=Raleway&family=Roboto&family=Rubik&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Figtree:wght@500&family=Inter:wght@100;300;400;500&family=Montserrat&family=Plus+Jakarta+Sans:wght@400;500&family=Raleway&family=Roboto&family=Rubik&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Figtree:wght@500&family=Inter:wght@100;300;400;500&family=Plus+Jakarta+Sans:wght@400;500&family=Raleway&family=Roboto&family=Rubik&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<header>
  <nav class="nav">
    <span id="question" class="material-symbols-outlined" style="font-size:30px;">help</span>
    <span id="contact" class="material-symbols-outlined" style="font-size:30px;">mail</span>
    <span id="share" class="material-symbols-outlined" style="font-size:30px;">share</span>

    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">

  </div>
</div>
```

I was expecting the share icon to always be in the viewport.

Comment: Use flex and space-between on your nav and go from there

Comment: Do you want that your question, contact, share to be aligned left or one left one middle and one right?

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your question correctly, the share disappears, so if you use `position: absolute;` with `right: 10px` this aligns the share into top right.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px
}

#share {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Figtree', sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background: #212529;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 120px auto;
  padding: 0px 80px;
  background: white;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined" rel="stylesheet">


<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Figtree:wght@500&family=Inter:wght@100;300;400;500&family=Montserrat&family=Plus+Jakarta+Sans:wght@400;500&family=Raleway&family=Roboto&family=Rubik&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Figtree:wght@500&family=Inter:wght@100;300;400;500&family=Montserrat&family=Plus+Jakarta+Sans:wght@400;500&family=Raleway&family=Roboto&family=Rubik&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Figtree:wght@500&family=Inter:wght@100;300;400;500&family=Plus+Jakarta+Sans:wght@400;500&family=Raleway&family=Roboto&family=Rubik&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<header>
  <nav class="nav">
    <span id="question" class="material-symbols-outlined" style="font-size:30px;">help</span>
    <span id="contact" class="material-symbols-outlined" style="font-size:30px;">mail</span>
    <span id="share" class="material-symbols-outlined" style="font-size:30px;">share</span>

    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">

  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this fixes your probelm!